# Pandas rolling apply multiplication

Tags: pandas, apply, product, rolling-computation

I would have thought this would be a basic application of `pd.DataFrame().rolling()` or `pd.Series().rolling()`, but it appears that the pandas rolling function cannot handle scalar multiplication being applied to a rolling window; I am hoping I am wrong and someone can spot the error.

I am trying to take a rolling window of a series (or dataframe) and multiply each row of that series/dataframe by a series/dataframe of weights (these weights have been precomputed).  The code I thought should work is:

```
data.rolling(5).apply( lambda x: x*weights )
```

with

```
data = pd.Series( np.random.randint(1,101,2000) )

weights = pd.Series([ 0.10650, 0.1405310, 0.1854318, 0.2446788, 0.3228556 ])
```

I thought, data.rolling(5).apply( lambda x: x*weights ) would produce a new rolling series, but the following error is returned everytime "TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>".

I should note that the only reason that I am trying to multiply the weights is to apply a corr/cov/mean statistic on the new rolling seres/dataframe afterward...something like

```
rolling_weighted_corr  = data.rolling(5).apply( lambda x: x*weights ).corr()
```

Does anyone know how to multiply (scalar) a series with a rolling series to produce a new rolling series?

Comment: can you provide expected output for a smaller data set?

Comment: what do you want to do with the five rows after multiplication?  Sum them to return a row?

Comment: Have you looked at `pd.rolling_apply`

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want element-wise multiplication of separate 5-element windows by this weights vector?  Because in a rolling operation the window will shift by 1 (not by 5) and you will get the same element in the original series multiplied by five different values.  That does not seem like what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Yes, I do want to do an element-wise multiplication of the rolling series with the weights... to create a new rolling series (with the same window size; that's why the window size is 5 and there are 5 weight elements).  I would have thought that within pd.rolling() there would be an option for passing your own weights to the rolling series, but I haven't found anything like this in the documentation.

Comment: So, basically, what I want for me output is a new rolling series that has been adjusted by the weights I am passing to my original rolling series....


first adjusted rolling series = data[:5]*weights,
second adjusted rolling series = data[1:6]*weights,
third adjusted rolling series = data[2:7]*weights, and so on.  


This is just a new rolling series that has been adjusted by the weights I am trying to pass to the original rolling series.  Once I have the new rolling series, I can tack on .corr() or .mean() to get the statistics I want for the adjusted rolling window.

Answer (score 0):

Scipy can do this with `signal.convolve`.  For example, using the  `mode="same"` flag will return an array of the same size as `data` where a centered window around each row is multiplied by weights and summed (thus, `np.sum(weights)` is used to normalize).  Example:

```
from scipy import signal

data_smoothed = signal.convolve(data, weights, mode="same")/np.sum(weights)


np.var(data) # 836.0666897499997
np.var(data_smoothed) # 185.52213418878418
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I looked into scipy.signal.convolve a little.  This is clearly doing something close to the desired output, but it doesn't match a manual check on the rolling window calculation.

Comment: According to documentation, the adjusted rolling series should be given by:
data_adj = pd.Series( signal.convolve( data, weights, mode = 'full' ) )

Note: the sum of the weights = 1, so no impact on output.  The output of this is:
0    1.065026369243
1    4.600389827127
2   13.099424806537
3   23.994460785031
4   41.991636602235
5   61.585449624559
6   78.706424681927
7   76.589074943834
8   83.593457811582
9   76.860400877013

Comment: However, a manual check (window-by-window) on the calculation gives:

|            scipy      |    manual          |
|-----------| ----------------- |
|0 | 1.065026369243 |1.065026369243|
|1 |4.600389827127|4.215932158194|
|2 |13.099424806537 |12.238502834840|
|3 |23.994460785031 |15.414764883561|
|4 |41.991636602235 |31.316995365661|

Note: the manual calculation is just: 'data[i:i+1].reset_index(drop=True)*weights'